# MySQL - Find the same day every month

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have created a system that will be calculating data every month based on when a user has signed up.

I will be running a daily cron job to grab all users who need there information calculated, and I would like to grab all the users for each day.

If users all signed up on something like `2011-01-01`

A simply query would find that (if yesterday was the end of the period):

```
SELECT `user_id` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE DAY( `date_created` ) = DAY( DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) )
```

It gets more complicated if they signed up on  `2011-03-31`

What query can I use to make sure that on `2011-04-30` they would be found?

My guess is something like

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `table`
WHERE 
    DAY( `date_created` ) = DAY( DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) )
    OR DAY( DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ) < DAY( `date_created` )
        AND LAST_DAY( DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ) = DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

That does not seem very efficient, nor do I know if it would work (though I suspect it does).

Is there a tried an true method? Or any better way to do this?

Comment: im not clear about your question, is it for getting the users signed in the specific day of the month, that is if I have signed in on june 13th, I should get my user id up on running the query today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is check if it's the first of the month, if it is do a `>=` comparison, otherwise do a `=` comparison.

```
WHERE IF(DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) = 1,
    DAY( `date_created` ) >= DAY(DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY )),
    DAY( `date_created` ) = DAY(DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ))
)
```

So on the 1st of March, it will update users who registered on or after the 28th (in a non leap year).